# TypeError: react_1.useEffect is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-component, react-lifecycle

I am trying to make us of useEffect in my React component but I am encountering an issue with the following error:

> TypeError: react_1.useEffect is not a function

and

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: react_1.useState is not a function

I have imported the libraries like this

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
```

and have the useEffect like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("This is cool")
}, [intentButton])
```

The react version is 16.7.0

Comment: What is the version of react you are using?

Comment: @dEBA M The react version is 16.7.0

Comment: "Hooks are a new addition in React 16.8. They let you use state and other React features without writing a class"
From React docs. Try using a later version of React and see if it fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

this is because the react V16.7 does not have hooks

The resolution is to downgrade to

```
   npm i react@next react-dom@next
```

which as of 2018/12/20 is 16.7.0-alpha.2:

```
yarn add react@next react-dom@next
```

then lose the test renderer:

```
 import React from 'react'
 import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
 import App from './App'
 it('renders without crashing', () => {
    const div = document.createElement('div')
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, div)
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div)
 })
```

This is what `package.json` should be:

```
  "react": "^16.7.0-alpha.2",
  "react-dom": "^16.7.0-alpha.2",
```